# Beamer interaction remove footline

Tags: beamer

Can anyone explain why the MWE below is bad? When I compile it, there is no footline on the first page!?!

I use the `<+>` and `<+->` in order to not having to explicitly having to specify the various overlays.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\author{Author}
\institute{Department}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame title}

  \begin{onlyenv}<+>
    Overlay 1, just one
  \end{onlyenv}

  \begin{onlyenv}<+->
    Overlay 2

    \onslide<+->

    more text
  \end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's something with the inclusion or exclusion of `\onslide<+->`, at least.

Comment: I know, remove it and the footline appears again.

Comment: Add braces around `{more text}`, and it seems to fix it.

Comment: Doesn't for me (and would be a strange fix), I still have no footer on overlay 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding this requires a subtle reading of the `beamer` manual. (Note: this is Till's text, not mine!) For `beamer` 3.36, on page 80 one finds the description of `\onslide`. The given syntax is

```
\onslide⟨modifier⟩<⟨overlay specification⟩>{⟨text⟩}
```

where the `{⟨text⟩}` argument is *optional*. There is then detail of what happens if there is no `{⟨text⟩}`, and importantly

> You need not call this command in the same TeX group, its effect transcends block groups.

That's important because you've said `\onslide<+->`, which in the example means `<2->`. What then happens is that this applies to *everything on the frame* after this point, *including* the picture environment used to draw the footer! Not all footer-like elements follow (internally) at the end of the frame, so things like the navigation symbols survive.

If you use the optional `{⟨text⟩}` then `\onslide` behaves like `\uncover`, which *does* obey groupings.

Comment: The fact that `beamer` uses TikZ internally in a lot of places makes things a bit 'interesting'!