# Beamer footline breaks in Tabular (no "\pause error")

Tags: tables, header-footer

There is a strange footline break when (apperantly) the last row of a tabular is printed. I know such footline breaks from tikz, where one just has to put an "\onslide <1->" right before the "\end{frame}". However, this doesn't work for the footline break in tabular. Does anyone have some solution?

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Title}
\pause
    \begin{table}[H]
        \footnotesize
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l}
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text line 1}  \tabularnewline \midrule

            \onslide<3->

            Text line 1 \tabularnewline

            \onslide<5->        

            Text line 2 \tabularnewline

            \onslide<7->

            Text line 3 \tabularnewline

            \onslide<9->

            Text line 4 \tabularnewline

        \end{tabular*} 

    \end{table}


    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \onslide<1-3>
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
    \onslide<4-5>
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
    \onslide<6-7>
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}};
    \onslide<8-9>
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
    \onslide<10-10>
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \onslide<1->        
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is related to the `table`? Did you try with the `table` environment and its contents commented out?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/256878/134144 might be interesting as well.

Answer (score 1):

Found a working solution: Putting an "\onslide<1->" right before the end of the tikzpicture AND right before the end of the tabular environment solved the problem. No footlinebreaks anymore!

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Title}

    \pause

    \begin{table}[H]
        \footnotesize

        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l}

            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text line 1}  \tabularnewline \midrule

            \onslide<3->

            Text line 1 \tabularnewline

            \onslide<5->        

            Text line 2 \tabularnewline

            \onslide<7->

            Text line 3 \tabularnewline

            \onslide<9->

            Text line 4 \tabularnewline
            \onslide<1->                
        \end{tabular*} 

    \end{table}


    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \onslide<1-3>
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
    \onslide<4-5>
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
    \onslide<6-7>
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}};
    \onslide<8-9>
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
    \onslide<10-10>
    \node{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
    \onslide<1->
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```